# Coordinate ring of a variety Miles Reid Undergraduate Commutative Algebra: [6.9]

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

I am reading Miles Reid *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra* and I am working through some of the exercises in chapter 6.

6.9: For $A=k[V]$ the coordinate ring of a variety $V\subset k^n$, and $f\in A$, prove that $A[1/f]$ is the coordinate ring of a variety $V_f\subset k^{n+1}$ which is a natural one to one correspondence with the (Zariski) open set $V\setminus V(f)$

I believe I want to use the previous problem (6.8)
 If $S=\{1,f,f^2,f^3,\ldots \}$, is a multiplicative set of $A$, then $Spec(A_f)\subset Spec(A)$ is the complement of the closed set $\mathcal{V}(f)$.

My proof: 
By definition, $\mathcal{V}(f):=\{P\in Spec(A) : f\in P \}$. Hence, $Spec(A) \setminus \mathcal{V}(f)= \{P\in Spec(A) : f \notin P\}= \{P \in Spec(A): 1,f,f^2,\ldots \notin P\}$ as each $P$ is prime.  Thus, $Spec(A) \setminus \mathcal{V}(f) = \{ P \in Spec(A) : P\cap S= \varnothing \}$. As per the hint, by Corollarry 6.3(iv), we can identify $Spec(A_f)$ with $Spec(A) \setminus \mathcal{V}(f)$

Using this lemma, and the definition of $A=k[V]=k[X_1,\ldots X_n]/I$ for $I=rad(I)=\{\text{ polynomials that vanish on all points }P\in V\}$, I can view any $f\in A$ as a polynomial function $f:V\to k$ meaning I can write $f$ as polynomial coordinates $x_i$ then $A[1/f]=k[V,1/f]$ I have coordinates for the first $n$ components but I am lost as to how $1/f$ changes it. Intuitively, it makes sense that this will be the set of points that don't vanish on $f$, but I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: note $A[1/f] \cong A[u]/<uf-1>$.

Comment: Hmm thats a good point. Maybe I should try using Rabinowitch's trick.

Comment: Since you know that $k[\mathrm{Spec}(A)]=A$ and that $V_f =\mathrm{Spec}(A_f)$ then you only need to prove that $A_f\simeq A[1/f]$